# External Css or Assets from local storage not working on Node Application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Created a server.js which indicates to index.html file.(server.js and index.html locates on the same folder).
In that html I couldn't use any styling from external css file or any assests from local storage. But inline css & images from internet is working fine.

server.js

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const http=require('http').createServer(app)
const PORT=process.env.PORT||3000;

http.listen(PORT,()=>{

})

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{    
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
})
```

The HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/frontEnd/style.css">
    <title>Chat App</title>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="container contain" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                <div class="navBar">
                    <img src="/frontEnd/ChatAppLogo.png">
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="/frontEnd/script.js"></script>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide a path for static files using `express.static(rootDir)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your files are inside `frontEnd` folder. Like in here:

`<img src="/frontEnd/ChatAppLogo.png">`

Also you don't serve static files anywhere in your code. It should be something like [in the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

`app.use(express.static('public'))`